# Oracle SQL - thinks it's missing a right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax-error, parentheses

```
CREATE TABLE WORKORDERS
    (wo# NUMBER(10) CONSTRAINT WORKORDERS_wo#_pk PRIMARY KEY,
        proj# NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
        wo_Desc VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,                 
        wo_Assigned VARCHAR2(50),
        wo_Hours NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
        wo_Start DATE(YYYY-MM-DD),
        wo_Due DATE(YYYY-MM-DD),
        wo_Complete CHAR(1)
        CONSTRAINT WORKORDER_wo_Complete_ck CHECK(wo_Complete IN('Y','N')),
        CONSTRAINT WORKORDER_proj#_fk FOREIGN KEY (proj#) REFERENCES PROJECT (proj#),
        CONSTRAINT WORKORDERS_wo_Desc_unq UNIQUE,
        CONSTRAINT WORKORDERS_wo_Hours_ck CHECK(wo_Hours > 0))
```

The problem oracle has underlined for me is

```
wo_Start DATE(YYYY-MM-DD),
            E(Y
```

It suggests adding a REFERENCE or CONSTRAINT but I don't think either will fix it. It looks fine and I'm unsure of why it would only give me an error that spans 3 characters.

Comment: I am not familiar with providing a format for `DATE` in Oracle (or any other database for that matter).

Comment: Oh, I figured it would need it (or it was optional for preference). Removing it now claims to be missing a left parenthesis. SQL Error: ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis
00906. 00000 -  "missing left parenthesis"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect the following to work, if the foreign key reference works:

```
CREATE TABLE WORKORDERS (
    wo# NUMBER(10) CONSTRAINT WORKORDERS_wo#_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    proj# NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    wo_Desc VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,                 
    wo_Assigned VARCHAR2(50),
    wo_Hours NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    wo_Start DATE,
    wo_Due DATE,
    wo_Complete CHAR(1),
    CONSTRAINT WORKORDER_wo_Complete_ck CHECK (wo_Complete IN ('Y','N')),
    CONSTRAINT WORKORDER_proj#_fk FOREIGN KEY (proj#) REFERENCES PROJECT (proj#),
    CONSTRAINT WORKORDERS_wo_Desc_unq UNIQUE (wo_Desc),
    CONSTRAINT WORKORDERS_wo_Hours_ck CHECK (wo_Hours > 0)
);
```

Problems:

- Illegal date format.
- Missing comma before constraints.
- Incomplete unique constraint.